# Working for a US company, from abroad

Tags: contracts, contractors, telecommute, visa

There are now a number of IT companies (including StackExchance itself! :) ) that are looking for candidates all over the world, allowing them to work remotely.

I have some questions about this kind of job/work relationship: for what I understood, you are going to work as a contractor, and invoice the company monthly, paying for taxes, medical insurance etc. in the country you live in.

- Are there other ways?
- Do you need a VISA for this kind of relationship?
- If you do not need a VISA, how do you handle visits for to the company you are working for?
- Is it possible to set-up an agreement, for this kind of relationship, that gives you some "security"? (something like a 6 month or 1 year recurring contract, with penalties for early termination?)

Thank you for any contribution!

Comment: I think these are great questions but right now there are way too many for a single question on this site format - I would suggest focusing on questions individually.

Comment: I wondered if they were too many myself, however they are all more or less related. I would give it a try, maybe someone else faced a similar situation, had the same doubts and found all the answers. Otherwise, I will edit the question and maybe break it in 2 or three parts

Comment: You can also link them in the question - I've done this before myself when having similar and related questions :)

Comment: @enderland I will probably go in that direction, but this is my first question here and I did not want to give the impression of "spamming", posting multiple related questions at the same time

Comment: @dema80 if you are ever unsure you can always catch some of us on chat and double check. http://chat.stackexchange.com/ Welcome to The Workplace

Comment: @SpikyBlue thanks, I am more used to StackOverflow, where (due to the very high traffic) this is not so common...